# multiple errors in R

Tags: r, xlsx, rjava

I am trying to get three_d_array for dataset using R language. I have the same data description in different files so I ran my code for each file by changing the name only. The following is my code

```
#Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7")
install.packages('lazyeval')
install.packages("xlsx")
install.packages("rJava")
options(java.parameters = "-Xmx10000m")
#options(java.parameters="-Xmx4000m")
options(java.home="C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/")
library(rJava)
library(xlsx)
raw23370 <- read.xlsx("C:\\Users\\Taqwa\\Desktop\\stations\\stations\\23370.xlsx",1)
out <- createWorkbook()
three_d_array <- array(0,dim = c(92, 6, 600))
#options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1000m")
for (i in 1:600){
 candy = 1:nrow(raw23370)

 B=sample(candy,nrow(raw23370) , replace=T)

 a=raw23370[B,]
 assign(paste0("sheet", i), createSheet(wb = out, sheetName = as.character(i)))
     addDataFrame(x = a, sheet = eval(as.name(paste0("sheet", i))))
 }
 saveWorkbook(out, "C:\\Users\\Taqwa\\Desktop\\stations\\23370_output.xlsx")
```

I kept getting multiple errors after running the code for file number 20, 
the following are my errors

```
library(rJava)
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Taqwa/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’
> library(xlsx)
Loading required package: rJava
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Taqwa/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded
> raw23370 <- read.xlsx("C:\\Users\\Taqwa\\Desktop\\stations\\stations\\23370.xlsx",1)
Error: could not find function "read.xlsx"
> out <- createWorkbook()
Error: could not find function "createWorkbook"
> three_d_array <- array(0,dim = c(92, 6, 600))
> #options(java.parameters = "-Xmx1000m")
> for (i in 1:600){
+   candy = 1:nrow(raw23370)
+   
+   B=sample(candy,nrow(raw23370) , replace=T)
+   
+   a=raw23370[B,]
+   assign(paste0("sheet", i), createSheet(wb = out, sheetName = as.character(i)))
+   # you don't really need your three_d_array
+   addDataFrame(x = a, sheet = eval(as.name(paste0("sheet", i))))
+ }
Error in nrow(raw23370) : object 'raw23370' not found
> saveWorkbook(out, "C:\\Users\\Taqwa\\Desktop\\stations\\23370_output.xlsx")
Error: could not find function "saveWorkbook"
```

Could anyone provide help

Comment: If you need to read Excel files, you may want to look at the `readxl` package.  It does have the dependences(i.e. Java) that other packages have.

Comment: ITYM does _not_

Comment: @TaqwaHadidi: You need to fix your installation of `rJava` first. Search SO with terms "install rJava windows"

Comment: I tried without success.

Comment: It looks like your jre installation is not found by rJava. make sure the relevant links are okay

Comment: Could you help me in that by steps please @ekstroem

Comment: I reinstall Java and make sure that everything works,